# How to prove that this sequence diverges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I know that this sequence diverges but I am not sure how to prove it diverges. If someone can help me out, that would be great. Thanks.

$$a_n = 1+\frac{n}{(n+1)}\cos\frac{n\pi}{2}$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do these kind of problems, it's helpful to notice what is and isn't important.

If you remember your limit laws

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} 1+\frac{n}{(n+1)}\cos\frac{n\pi}{2} = 1 + \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{(n+1)} \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \cos \frac{n\pi}{2}$$

You'll find that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{(n+1)} = 1$$

So really the whole thing just becomes:

$$1 + \lim_{n \to \infty} \cos \frac{n\pi}{2}$$

Does $\cos \frac{n\pi}{2}$ converge or diverge?

Comment: It diverges, thanks for the refresher on difficult problems like these.